# Cannot connect SocketIO server from docker container to outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, socket.io, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my SocketIO server within a NodeJS docker container but I'm getting this message on my client:

```
GET http://localhost:4500/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MPdyL6j net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

My Dockerfile for the server looks like this:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /
RUN apk update && apk upgrade && \
apk add --no-cache bash git openssh
RUN npm install -g nodemon
# Copy package.json
COPY package.json /package.json
# Install packages
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4500

CMD nodemon ./server/index.js
```

And within my docker-compose file I have:

```
services:
  socketio:
    build: ./packages/public/socketio
    hostname: socketio
    restart: always
    container_name: socketio
    volumes:
      - ./packages/public/socketio:/server
      - ./packages/config:/config
    environment:
      - PORT=4500
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    ports:
      - "4500:4500"
    depends_on: 
      - redis
```

Finally this is how I init the server (within a class):

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const server = app.listen(PORT);
    this.ioServer = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    ...
```

I think I'm doing it correctly, **if I execute the same server from outside a container I can connect using**:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4500/', { 'forceNew': true });
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Client connected...');
  socket.on('new_order', (message) => {
    console.log(message);
  });
```

But not using it from inside Docker.